# Динамическая "передача картинки экрана " без вай фай?

Tags: android, shell

Возможно ли осуществить динамическую  трансляцию экрана смартфона без соеденения по wi fi и USB . 
Только  при  наличие мобильного интернета . 
Нашёл решение- снимать скриншоты с экрана скриптом и с помощью синхронизации смотреть  их в облаке.
А возможно ли что то подобное , только в реальном времени ?

Comment: Прям сплю и вижу, full HD, по нестабильному каналу, через охренелеард коммутаторов и реалтайм. Жаль, что это все сон...

Answer (score 0):

Все возможно, только надо знать как. По поводу снятия экрана смартфона - скриншотами неэффективно, имеет смысл сразу писать видео(что то вроде этого: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336338/screen-video-record-of-current-activity-android ). Далее, наличие моб интернета, тут погуглите. Насчет облака, идея неплохая, но задержки будут большие, лучше прямой канал. И да, моб.сеть. нестабильна